# c++ why the second input is ignored?

Tags: c++

I need to check whether digit was entered and if not, ask for correct input.
Second input is ignored for some reason.

(There should be "while" instead of "if" in the final version, but I replaced it to "if" for debug to avoid eternal loops)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int number = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter some digit:\n";
    std::cin >> number;

    if (!isdigit(number)) 
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong input, please enter digit\n";
        std::cin >> number;
    }
}
```

Comment: put a **std::cin.getchar()** before it

Comment: `int number;` can accept more than a single digit, so with `std::cin >> number;` you're accidentally asking for the entire number all at once rather than digit by digit. `char number;` should be more suitable, [but watch out for the issue raised here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit#Notes).

Comment: `number` is an `int`, so it can only be an integer. `isdigit` checks if a character represents a digit. Instead you need to check whether `std::cin >> number` successfully read an integer.

Comment: If you call `std::isdigit(1)` it will return with zero (false), because it's not a digit *character*. `std::isdigit('1')` will return non-zero (true) though. And note that `1 != '1'`.

Comment: Or read the input as a string and see if it can be successfully converted to a number.

Comment: In any case, reading about the functions you want to use is generally considered good.

Comment: It is unfortunate that `isdigit` accepts `int`, otherwise you could get at least a conversion warning, but back in the day it was the only way to be able to pass around out-of-band control information.

Comment: Kindly also share the sample input on which you are testing this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in using `isdigit()` on an `int`, it only makes sense to use it with a `char`, as it looks for *characters* between `'0'..'9'`, not *integers* between `0..9`.

If `cin >> number` fails to read in a valid integer, it will put the stream into a failure state, which blocks further input.  You must `clear()` that state, and also `ignore()` the erroneous input, before you can read in further input.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int number;

    std::cout << "Please enter a single digit:\n";

    do
    {
        if (std::cin >> number)
        {
            if (number >= 0 && number <= 9)
                break;

            std::cout << "Wrong input, please enter a single digit\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong input, please enter a valid digit\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    while (true);

    std::cout << "You entered: " << number << std::endl;
}
```